# Confluent Kafka connect distributed mode jdbc connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We have successfully used MySQL - kafka data ingestion using jdbc standalone connector but now facing issue in using the same in distributed mode (as kafka connect service ).

Command used for standalone connector which works fine -

```
/usr/bin/connect-standalone /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties /etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-mysql.properties
```

Now we have stopped this one and started the kafka connect service in distributed mode like this -

```
systemctl status confluent-kafka-connect
● confluent-kafka-connect.service - Apache Kafka Connect - distributed
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/confluent-kafka-connect.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-11-14 22:52:49 CET; 41min ago
     Docs: http://docs.confluent.io/
 Main PID: 130178 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/confluent-kafka-connect.service
           └─130178 java -Xms256M -Xmx2G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -Djava.a...
```

2 nodes are currently running the connect service with same `connect-distributed.properties` file .

```
bootstrap.servers=node1IP:9092,node2IP:9092
group.id=connect-cluster
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

The connect service is UP and running but it doesn't load the connectors defined under `/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties`.

What should be done to the service so that whenever you hit the command `systemctl start confluent-kafka-connect` , it runs the service and starts the defined connectors under `/etc/kafka-connect-*/` just like when you run a standalone connector manually providing paths to properties files.

Answer (score 2):

> it runs the service and starts the defined connectors under `/etc/kafka-connect-*/`

That's not how distributed mode works... It doesn't know which property files you want to load, and it doesn't scan those folders<sup>1</sup>

With standalone-mode the `N+1` property files that you give are loaded immediately, yes, but for connect-distributed, you must use [HTTP POST calls to the Connect REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html#post--connectors).

---

Confluent Control Center or Landoop's Connect UI can provide a nice management web portal for these operations.

By the way, if you have more than one broker, I'll suggest increasing the replica factors on those connect topics in the `connect-distributed.properties` file.

<sup>1. <sub>It might be a nice feature if it did, but then you have to ensure connectors are never deleted/stopped in distributed mode, and you just end up in an inconsistent state with what's running and the files that are on the filesystem.</sub></sup>

Comment: I am invoking the connector using : curl -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 10.30.72.218:8083/connectors/ -d '{"name": "linuxemp-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X:3306/linux_db?user=groot&password=pwd","table.whitelist": "emp","mode": "timestamp","incrementing.column.name":"empid","topic.prefix": "mysqlconnector-" } }'    . I already have the connector drivers in the plugin path and it is kept on all connect nodes .

Comment: But still getting this error -  {"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for

Comment: "No suitable driver found" would mean the JAR isnt being loaded from the plugin path (more specifically the connect-jdbc directory). If standalone mode worked, and you're running distributed mode on the same machine, then I'm not sure why that'd happen

Comment: @Tony i think you should make sure that you've added the mysql jdbc driver library to the `${confluent.install.dir}/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/` directory

Comment: @marius Feel free to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53321726/kafka-connect-jdbc-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-only-when-using-distribute

Answer (score 1):

I can describe what I did for starting the jdbc connector in distributed mode:

I am using on my local machine, `confluent` CLI utility for booting up faster the services.

```
./confluent start
```

Afterwords I stopped kafka-connect

```
./confluent stop connect
```

and then I proceed to manually start the customized `connect-distributed` on two different ports (`18083` and `28083`)

```
➜  bin ./connect-distributed ../etc/kafka/connect-distributed-worker1.properties

➜  bin ./connect-distributed ../etc/kafka/connect-distributed-worker2.properties
```

NOTE: Set `plugin.path` setting to the full (and not relative) path (e.g.: plugin.path=/full/path/to/confluent-5.0.0/share/java)

Then i can easily add a new connector

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/full/path/to/confluent-5.0.0/etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-sqlite.json http://localhost:18083/connectors
```

This should do the trick.

As already pointed out by [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) consider a replication factor of at least 3 for the kafka brokers in case you're dealing with stuff that you don't want to lose in case of outage of one of the brokers.

Comment: `confluent start` will run distributed mode... Why did you use two processes, though?

Answer (score 0):

The connector in distributed mode can not be deployed by property file as in a standalone mode. Using REST API instead, pls refer to https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/configuring.html#connect-managing-distributed-mode